# DOMNodeInserted on html tag runs many times, need to make it run just once in a timeframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (event) {
    console.log('change');
}, false);
```

Above is a method (obviously I'll be changing around the contents but a log is good enough for test purposes). I need this to run only once per page change (the easiest way I've found of doing this is a timer) however it runs many times as there are many child nodes to the html tag. Is there any way I can ensure that this "console.log('change')" area of the eventListener only runs once in a specific timeframe? Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem as you're asking about your attempted solution, not the actual issue. Why do you need to do this? If you want to track what elements are appended to the DOM and when, I'd suggest using a MutationObserver instead

Comment: I need to do this as I am making a chrome extension that modifies the DOM and overlays statistics on the page however the website I wish to overlay things on doesn't refresh each time a new page is loaded. So to get around this my aim is to run my function that gathers the information from the page and implements the overlay whenever an item on the page is changed.

Answer (score 0):

[Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) are

> **Deprecated**
>   This feature has been removed from the Web standards.
>   Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of
>   being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible;
>   see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your
>   decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.
>
> Mutation events provide a mechanism for a web page or an extension to
>   get notified about changes made to the DOM. **Use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)
>   instead if possible**.

Comment: Thanks I'm definitely going to look into that!